# Speed Up Matching Value Processing (If ... = ... Then ...)

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops

So I currently have code which looks like this: I'm basically trying to check that if one sheet's column B can be found in another sheet's column C, then I will, in that other sheet's row where I found the B value, take its H column value and copy it to the current sheet's AI column. This process will be repeated for every row in the B column.

The problem I'm encountering is that it's running way too slow, even with turning off screenupdates etc. This makes sense because there are over 50000 values it has to loop through along with all the values it has to lookup. I would really appreciate it if someone could look it through and come up with potential ways i could speed up the process. Thank you.

```
Sub Calculation()

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

  Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
  LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 5 To LastRow

  Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
  Dim anyRow As Long

    For anyRow = 4 To 500
      If wb1.Sheets("Total").Cells(anyRow, 2).Value =                    wb1.Sheets("Record").Cells(i, 3).Value Then
        wb1.Sheets("Record").Cells(i, 35).Value =     wb1.Sheets("Total").Cells(anyRow, 8).Value
      End If
    Next anyRow
  Next i

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you resetting `wb1` every iteration? I'm not sure, how bad that is though. Same for `Dim anyRow`.

Comment: in which sheet you find the last row for A column?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct True. I should leave those out of the loop. It still runs incredibly slow though :(

Comment: @charrrrrrrr you loose up to 99% of the time by accessing the cells... just load them up in an array and then check the array-values... also you should leave the inner loop if a match is found... that said, if you just want to check if the value exists in the B4:B500 range, then use `isnumeric(application.match(...))` which is extremely fast!

Comment: @DirkReichel Thanks for the response! However, it doesn't seem to work. I actually already know that the value will exist in the B4:B500 range and need to just take the proper row of H. To put it into context, I pretty much have a list of "keys" & all their info in `Sheets("Total")`. Then, I have a bunch of those same keys in random orders (with lots of repeats) in `Sheets ("Record")` & all of them, including duplicates have to be linked back up to the original key's info in column H. :/

Comment: @DirkReichel & Also, I actually have over 50000 values, not 20000 like I mistyped before, so I'm not sure how to get it to run without crashing :(

Comment: @NanAvanIllai The ActiveSheet / `Sheets("Record")`!

Comment: @charrrrrrrr after changing your initial code `...Sheets("Total").Cells(i, 8)...` to `...Sheets("Total").Cells(anyRow, 8)...` that is true... but running it twice is still a lot faster then looping the whole range... also `match` is used for the `4 To 500` range and will not error out (tested it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want (a lot faster):

```
Sub Calculation()
  With ThisWorkbook
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rngVal(3) As Variant
    rngVal(0) = .Sheets("Total").Range("B4:B500").Value
    rngVal(1) = .Sheets("Record").Range("C5:C" & LastRow).Value
    rngVal(2) = .Sheets("Record").Range("AI5:AI" & LastRow).Value
    rngVal(3) = .Sheets("Total").Range("H4:H500").Value
    For i = 1 To LastRow - 4
      If IsNumeric(Application.Match(rngVal(1)(i, 1), rngVal(0), 0)) Then rngVal(2)(i, 1) = rngVal(3)(Application.Match(rngVal(1)(i, 1), rngVal(0), 0), 1)
    Next
    .Sheets("Record").Range("AI5:AI" & LastRow).Value = rngVal(2)
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think `rngVal(3)(i, 1)` is not the value you want to copy, you want the value from the row where the match was found.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct true... he changed `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total").Cells(i, 8).Value` to `wb1.Sheets("Total").Cells(anyRow, 8).Value` after i posted my answer...

Comment: @DirkReichel Sorry about editing it right after, haha that's when I realized as well... But anyway, your code works wonders. It was just what I needed! It only takes 10.77 seconds to run it now, which is amazing considering how much data I have. Thanks!

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Thanks for catching that! :)

Answer (score 2):

Using a dictionary will allow you to iterate each sheet just 1 time.  A dictionary stores information in {Key, Value} pairs.  Keys are unique and used as lookup the associated Value.

Here we are adding {Key, Value} pairs from Sheets("Total") to the dictionary

```
k = .Cells(i, 2).Text
v = .Cells(i, 2)
If Not dictTotals.Exists(k) Then dictTotals.Exists.Add k, v
```

Now as we iterate Sheets("Record"), we check to see if we have a matching.  If so we assign the Key's Values to .Cells(i, 35).Value.

```
k = .Cells(i, 3).Text
If dictTotals.Exists(k) Then .Cells(i, 35).Value = dictTotals(k)
```

I extrapolated this method to handle toggling events.  In this way, we can focus on the Calculation() methods main task.

```
Sub Calculation()
    EnableAllEvents True
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim dictTotals
    Dim k As String, v As Variant
    Set dictTotals = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Sheets("Total")
        For i = 5 To LastRow
            k = .Cells(i, 2).Text
            v = .Cells(i, 2)
            If Not dictTotals.Exists(k) Then dictTotals.Exists.Add k, v
        Next
    End With

    With Sheets("Record")
        LastRow = Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 4 To LastRow
            k = .Cells(i, 3).Text
            If dictTotals.Exists(k) Then .Cells(i, 35).Value = dictTotals(k)
        Next
    End With

    EnableAllEvents False
End Sub


Sub EnableAllEvents(bEnableEvents As Boolean)
    With Application
        If bEnableEvents Then .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic Else .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = bEnableEvents
        .DisplayStatusBar = bEnableEvents
        .EnableEvents = bEnableEvents
        .DisplayPageBreaks = bEnableEvents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't even know you could do that in VBA. Will definitely read up on it. Thanks for your in depth answer. Really appreciate it!

Comment: I think you need to change `v = .Cells(i, 2)` to `v = .Cells(i, 8)`, `dictTotals.Exists.Add` to `dictTotals.Add` and `anyRow` to `i` but then it's pretty damn fast